# Azure Scheduler TLS 1.0 calling MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ssl

We are using Azure Scheduler (AS) to make calls to an HTTPS URL. This has been working with no issues until now. We have disabled TLS 1.0 on there hosting server due to a security requirement and now AS now logs "ConnectFailure Unable to connect to the remote server"

I would have thought that AS would negotiate the connection. Is anyone aware of any issue or is there anything I can do in my MVC app force AS to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to Azure support and it turns out that Azure Scheduler currently requires a TLS 1.0 for https endpoint. There was no timescale given by Microsoft for any change to this.

Comment: experienced the same issue. unbelievable. the Azure Scheduler is a hunk of junk. It only remembers UTC offsets, not actual timezones. It can't connect over TLS 1.2. You can't use the portal to setup a job to add to a queue in a non-classic storage account. Just utter bollocks.